# Do Google Ads get attributed to the most specific targeting when multiple rules overlap?

Tags: advertising, google-ads, geotargeting, cpc-ads, ad-targeting

Anyone know what the specificity hierarchy is on Google Ads? Does it always attribute the results to the most specific target?

For example if you have a radius inside a radius will it attribute the ad results to the smaller radius? Same for keywords that are exact match vs phrase match?

Comment: Just a point of interest regarding match types in Google Ads, there's been some changes recently (for instance, phrase is now essentially BMM) and I've seen unexpected behaviour, especially on exact match. So a textbook answer to this might actually not reflect reality.